# How to debug a time limited exceeded error in a code challenge?

Tags: time, c++14, limit

The following code is written in C++14 for a [Codechef problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/EXAMCHT). The time taken was 1.01 secs and it resulted in a "time limited exceeded" error. Is it some kind of integer overflow, or the time complexity is high? If it is, then please suggest me some corrections which I should do in the code to make it run?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    // problem code - EXAMCHT, Author - gamerrk1004
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
         int a,b,count=0;
         cin >> a >> b;
          for(int i=1;i<b;i++)
          {
               if((a-1)%i==(b-1)%i)
               {
                    count ++;
               }
          }
         cout << count << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the error here? I am getting a "time limit exceeded".

### Update

Earlier, I was using cout and endl but later I switched to printf, but the problem still hasn't got solved.

Comment: OK. Please get into the habit of editing the question to add new information (as I asked `:-)`). I have done this for you just now.

Comment: If it says it takes 1.01 seconds, it does not mean that it actually runs in that time but that it gets killer after 1 second  which is the Time limit for that problem.

Comment: (Btw, "TLE" may not be well understood outside of code challenge circles, so I tend to write it in full).